# Recover dropdown selector after page refresh

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown selector in JS, this is working -

```
String statename=request.getParameter("statename");  

function getstate() 
    {
        document.getElementById("srt").value = document.getElementById("State").value;
    }

<select id="State" onchange="getstate()">  <!--Call getstate() function-->
        <option value="111">All</option>
        <option value="228">Move</option>
        <option value="212">Clean</option>
        <option value="196">Cleaning</option>
        <option value="180">Ready</option>
        <option value="164">Occupied</option>
    </select><br><br>
    
    TextBox1<br>
    <input type="text" id="srt" name="statename" value="<%=statename%>" placeholder="get state value"><br>
    <button type="submit">Show</button>   
           
    <%
    System.out.println("the value of statename is   "  + statename);
    %>
```

Two items I would like are an auto-submit instead of the manual submit button - I have tried to add this to the getstate function (where logform is the name of the form in which the field exists)

```
getElemRefs("logform").submit();
```

Although the selected value is retained after the page refreshes, the dropdown selector always returns to its first label (All). I need some way of storing / recovering the selected label after the refresh.

Tried a number of options using session storage without sucess, but then I am a newbie so getting very confused with what code I should enter and where.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we already went through this earlier this week. You need to ajax the value to the server

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('State').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    fetch(`serverprocessThatHandlesState?state=${e.target.value}`)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text))
  })
})
```

```html
<select id="State">
  <option value="111">All</option>
  <option value="228">Move</option>
  <option value="212">Clean</option>
  <option value="196">Cleaning</option>
  <option value="180">Ready</option>
  <option value="164">Occupied</option>
</select>
```

If you INSIST on submitting, you need to set the value on the server

```html
<select id="State">
  <option value="111" <%= value === '111' ? ' selected' : '' %>>All</option>
  <option value="228" <%= value === '228' ? ' selected' : '' %>>Move</option>
```

... etc

OR use localStorage

(StackSnippets do not support windows storage so I made a [jsfiddle of the script below](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qtwn7b0x/)

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const state = document.getElementById('State');
  const selectedState = localStorage.getItem('state') || state.options[0].value;
  state.value = selectedState;
  state.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    localStorage.setItem('state', e.target.value)
  })
})
```

```html
<select id="State">
  <option value="111">All</option>
  <option value="228">Move</option>
  <option value="212">Clean</option>
  <option value="196">Cleaning</option>
  <option value="180">Ready</option>
  <option value="164">Occupied</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Appreciated mplungjan, local storage is showing some signs of working, I will do more testing. Eclipse is complaining re the syntax of the addEventListener implying that an expression is expected in the brackets, but if I add 'function' then the storage stops working.

Comment: Invalid function expression header

Comment: When? Where? The last script with localStorage does not work here at SO, but works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qtwn7b0x/)

Comment: Something odd when run inside Eclipse, code seems to run ok but Eclipse reporting syntax issue. Likely to be an Eclipse bug. Thanks again for your help.